# Coding of Binding Navigator buttons

Tags: vb.net, bindingnavigator

This is the first time I am working with the binding navigator and I cannot figure out how to get it working properly. In all the examples I have done there is no code showing for most of the buttons and they just work. In mine they are almost all grayed out. Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TripsDataSet.tblTrips' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TblTripsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TripsDataSet.tblTrips)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAll.Click
        'displays all trips
        Me.TblTripsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TripsDataSet.tblTrips)
        TblTripsDataGridView.DataSource = TripsDataSet.tblTrips
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnCount_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCount.Click
        'displays either business trips or pleasure trips
        Dim foundRows() As TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow
        Dim businesspleasure As String = ""
        If radBusiness.Checked Then
            businesspleasure = "B"
        ElseIf radPleasure.Checked Then
            businesspleasure = "P"
        End If

        foundRows = CType(Me.TripsDataSet.tblTrips.Select("BusinessPleasure = '" & businesspleasure & "'"), Trips_Project.TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow())

        Dim ds As New TripsDataSet.tblTripsDataTable
        For Each row As DataRow In foundRows
            ds.ImportRow(row)
        Next
        TblTripsDataGridView.DataSource = ds

        MessageBox.Show("Trips:  " & TblTripsDataGridView.RowCount - 1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnTrips_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTrips.Click
        Dim foundTrips() As TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow
        Dim originTrip As String
        Dim destinTrip As String

        If radOrAtl.Checked Then
            originTrip = "Atlanta"
        ElseIf radOrChi.Checked Then
            originTrip = "Chicago"
        ElseIf radOrLa.Checked Then
            originTrip = "Los Angeles"
        Else
            originTrip = "Nashville"
        End If

        If radDestAtl.Checked Then
            destinTrip = "Atlanta"
        ElseIf radDestChi.Checked Then
            destinTrip = "Chicago"
        ElseIf radDestLa.Checked Then
            destinTrip = "Los Angeles"
        Else
            destinTrip = "Nashville"
        End If
        foundTrips = CType(Me.TripsDataSet.tblTrips.Select(String.Format("Origin = '{0}' AND Destination = '{1}'", originTrip, destinTrip)), Trips_Project.TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow())

        Dim ds As New TripsDataSet.tblTripsDataTable
        For Each row As DataRow In foundTrips
            ds.ImportRow(row)
        Next

        TblTripsDataGridView.DataSource = ds

        MessageBox.Show("Total Trips:  " & TblTripsDataGridView.RowCount - 1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindingNavigatorSaveData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorSaveData.Click
        Try
            Me.Validate()
            Me.TblTripsBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.TripsDataSet)
            MessageBox.Show("Updates saved", "My Trips", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "My Trips", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click
        Try
            TblTripsBindingSource.AddNew()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Click
        Me.BindingNavigator1.BindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
        Try
            Me.Validate()
            Me.TblTripsBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.TripsDataSet)
            MessageBox.Show("Update Successful")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Which article(s) did you use/research?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A BindingNavigator is basically a UI for a BindingSource. The default items on a BindingNavigator map to the MoveFirst method, MovePrevious method, Position property, Count property, MoveNext method, MoveLast method, AddNew method and RemoveCurrent method of the associated BindingSource respectively. If you have not assigned a BindingSource object to the BindingSource property of the BindingNavigator then those items will be greyed out.

Note that in the Click event handler of your btnAll Button, you are binding your DataTable directly to your DataGridView. That makes your BindingNavigator useless. You need to bind your DataTable to your BindingSource and your BindingSource to your DataGridView. The items of the BindingNavigator then manipulate the BindingSource and thus affect anything the BindingSource is bound to, i.e. the DataGridView. If the BindingSource is not bound to the DataGridView then the BindingNavigator cannot have any effect on the DataGridView.

Comment: Thank you between your comments, and my text book I figured it out.  Your explanation helped immensely!